# Why is my score not updating? It just keeps displaying both scores as 0

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

```
import random
def rps():
    user_score = 0 
    comp_score = 0
    scoreboard = f'You: {user_score} \nComp: {comp_score}'
    while user_score < 3 or comp_score < 3:
        choice = ['r', 'p', 's']
        user = input('Choose [r] [p] or [s]: ')
        user = user.lower()
        comp = random.choice(choice)
        outcome = f"You chose {user} and I chose {comp}"
        if user == comp:
            print(scoreboard)
            print(outcome)
            print('Tie Game')
        elif user == 'r' and comp == choice[2] or user == 'p' and comp == choice[0] or user == 's' and comp == choice[1]:
            user_score += 1
            print(scoreboard)
            print(outcome, '\nYou win!')
        else:
            comp_score += 1 
            print(scoreboard)
            print(outcome, '\nI win')
    print(scoreboard)
```

I've tried putting the score and scoreboard in the while loop, leaving it out of the function. i dont know what else to do

Comment: You never update `scoreboard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `scoreboard` is set to `'You: 0 \nComp: 0'` in the beginning. It doesn't update automatically when the included variables change. To update the `scoreboard`, you should move the F-String (and only the F-String) inside the loop:

```py
import random
def rps():
    user_score = 0 
    comp_score = 0
    while user_score < 3 or comp_score < 3:
        choice = ['r', 'p', 's']
        user = input('Choose [r] [p] or [s]: ')
        user = user.lower()
        comp = random.choice(choice)
        outcome = f"You chose {user} and I chose {comp}"
        if user == comp:
            print(outcome, 'Tie Game')
        elif user == 'r' and comp == choice[2] or user == 'p' and comp == choice[0] or user == 's' and comp == choice[1]:
            user_score += 1
            print(outcome, '\nYou win!')
        else:
            comp_score += 1 
            print(outcome, '\nI win')
        scoreboard = f'You: {user_score} \nComp: {comp_score}'
        print(scoreboard)
    print(scoreboard)
```

This slightly changed the order of the prints because I wanted to avoid duplicating the F-String. You could put the `scoreboard = ...` and `print` into a function like `print_scoreboard` and call that to restore the order of your prints.

Answer (score 0):

The score does not update because the scoreboard is defined in the function. There are many ways to approach this, one way is to define your own function to update the scoreboard like this:

```
import random

def updateScoreBoard(userScore, cpuScore):
    scoreboard= f'You: {userScore} \nComp: {cpuScore} '
    print(f'You: {userScore} \nComp: {cpuScore}')
    #print(f'testing the value of userScore: {userScore}')
    #print(f'testing the value of cpuScore: {cpuScore}')
    
def rps():
    user_score = 0 
    comp_score = 0
    scoreboard = f'You: {user_score} \nComp: {comp_score}'
    while user_score < 3 and comp_score < 3:
        choice = ['r', 'p', 's']
        user = input('Choose [r] [p] or [s]: ')
        user = user.lower()
        comp = random.choice(choice)
        outcome = f"You chose {user} and I chose {comp}"
        if user == comp:
            #print(scoreboard)
            print(outcome)
            print('Tie Game')
            updateScoreBoard(user_score,comp_score)
            
        elif user == 'r' and comp == choice[2] or user == 'p' and comp == choice[0] or user == 's' and comp == choice[1]:
            user_score += 1
            #print(scoreboard)
            print(outcome, '\nYou win!')
            updateScoreBoard(user_score,comp_score)
            
        else:
            comp_score += 1 
            #print(scoreboard)
            print(outcome, '\nI win')
            updateScoreBoard(user_score,comp_score)
            
    print(scoreboard)
    
rps()
```

personally I would make the variables like scoreboard ,user_score, and comp_score all outside the def and then pass in the varibles into your function. However the example I provided works with the style you were writing it in.